# Spring security 3 http-basic authentication-success-handler

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

H i'm using spring security

for form-login i have

```xml
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/pages/index.html"
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login.html" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.html" invalidate-session="true" />
        <anonymous enabled='false'/>
</http>
```

here i can set an `authentication-success-handler-ref`, how can i add one to my basic authentication:

```xml
<http pattern="/REST/**" realm="REALM" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <http-basic  />
    <logout logout-url="/REST/logout" success-handler-ref="restLogoutSuccessHandler" />
</http>
```

i thought abour overriding BasicAuthenticationFilter, but how can i inject my cutom class for  `<http-basic  />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set an authentication success handler for BASIC authentication. You can, however, extend BasicAuthenticationFilter and override onSuccessfulAuthentication method:

```java
@Component("customBasicAuthFilter")
public class CustomBasicAuthFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    public CustomBasicAuthFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) {
        // Do what you want here
    }
}
```

Inject it in your security configuration with something like:

```xml
<http entry-point-ref="basicEntryPoint">
  <custom-filter ref="customBasicAuthFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  ...
</authentication-manager>
```

**Update:** Or with Java config instead of XML:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .addFilterAt(customBasicAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(basicEntryPoint);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide Java configuration for this XML?

Comment: When you do that you might want to disable httpBasic with `httpBasic().disable()`, or you will endup with two basic authentication filters.

Comment: I ran in a problem with this solution. Path forwarding or redirecting is not possible from within the filter chain.

Comment: How does that work? I get `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' available`

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can use **http-basic** in conjuction with **form-login**:

```xml
<http auto-config="true">
    ...
    <http-basic  />
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" ... />
    ...
</http>
```

BasicAuthenticationFilter will work.

**EDIT.**
If you want set up your overriden version of BasicAuthenticationFilter I think you need to:

1. Add it to filter chain at BASIC_AUTH_FILTER position as explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters)
2. Set up corresponding BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entry point via **entry-point-ref** attribute of **http** tag.

Comment: hi with this i always get the loginform, and no authentication challange

Comment: exactly, but basic auth must be used after form submit

Comment: but i need the basic auth-challange on my /REST urls

Comment: In this case try override BasicAuthenticationFilter. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` you can rely on Spring Security's [event mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/package-summary.html) and listen to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` by using the ApplicationListener interface:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEventListener implements
    ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>
{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent (AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
       // do what you want here
       // example: persist event to the database
    }
}
```

See also this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384001/474034