# Spring Security ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>

Tags: servlets, spring-security, listener

hi i've implemented an

```
ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>
```

when this event occurs, i want to set a cookie to the ServletResponse.

How can i access it?

Should i use a Filter? But how can a filter react to this event?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead. You will recieve HttpServletResponse as a parameter, so it will be no problem to work with coockies.

Comment: tried this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734537/spring-security-3-http-basic-authentication-success-handler it is not invoked with basic authentication