# Capture Login with Remember-Me in Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring, authentication, annotations, remember-me

**I want to detect when a user enter in my web page with Login form or remember-me cookie, and i want to execute code for register login, but this dont work. I dont know if exists other method for get my goal.**

I test it this solutions:

- http://learn.eastros.com/2012/07/11/springsecurity-capturing-rememberme-success-event/ . Here, its necessary define all class manually, filters, services and handler for login, logout and remember-me.
- [Recording logins with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346107/recording-logins-with-spring-security). This post try a easier solution, only defines a same handler for success Login and success remember-me. But dont work.
- For other hand, here [remember-me and authentication-success-handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575860/remember-me-and-authentication-success-handler/11678830#11678830) say that the handler for form-login and remember-me cant be same class, and i will should implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler for remmeber-me handler. Didnt work too.
- I tried define filter before and after position of REMEMBER_ME_FILTER too. Nothing.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is possible use a filter REMEMBER-ME using form-login?
2. security:http configuration needs indicate auto-config="false" and implement filters for login, logout and remember me as first link?
3. Is it Necessary that I implement my Service, and provider or I can implement filter only?

**My configuration**:

security-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"> 

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="customAuthenticationProvider">     
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider"></bean>
    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomUserDetailsService"></bean>
    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"></bean>
    <bean id="customRememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomRememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler"></bean>
    <bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler"></bean>
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"></bean>


    <bean id="customRememberMeService" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomRememberMeService">
        <constructor-arg value="MYKEY" />
        <constructor-arg ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customRememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- key needs to be same as that provided to customRememberMeService. -->
        <constructor-arg value="MYKEY"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="com.treebuk.config.CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="customRememberMeService"/>
    </bean>

    <security:http >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

        <security:form-login 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            login-page="/login"
            password-parameter="lgPassword" 
            username-parameter="lgUsername" />

        <security:logout
            success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" 
            logout-url="/logout"
            invalidate-session="true" />

        <security:csrf disabled="true" />

        <security:remember-me
            user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"
            remember-me-parameter="lgRememberMe"
            token-validity-seconds="100" />

        <security:custom-filter ref="rememberMeFilter" after="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" />

        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

</beans>
```

login.jsp

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
    <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="spring-security-redirect" value="<c:out value="${param.r}" />">
        <label for="txt_username">Usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_username" name="lgUsername" />
        <br />
        <label for="txt_password">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="txt_password" name="lgPassword">
        <br />
        <label for="chck_remeberme">Recordarme:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chck_remeberme" name="lgRememberMe" checked="checked" />
        <br />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Identificarse" />
    </form>
```

CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter {


    public CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, RememberMeServices rememberMeServices) {
        super(authenticationManager, rememberMeServices);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) {
        // TODO: User has been auto-logged using a remember me cookie, do your stuff here
        String x = "OK";
        x += "";
        String y = x;
    }
}
```

CustomRememberMeService.java ( **I comment body extractRememberMeCookie because else request.getHeader("remember-me") == null and throw a null exception**)

```
public class CustomRememberMeService extends TokenBasedRememberMeServices{

    public static final int TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 15; // 60*30=30 minutes

    public CustomRememberMeService(String key, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super(key, userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected String extractRememberMeCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
//        String rememberMe = request.getHeader("remember-me");
//        int startIndex = "remember-me=".length();
//        int endIndex = rememberMe.indexOf("; ", startIndex);
//        return rememberMe.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected int calculateLoginLifetime(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        return TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS;
    }

}
```

CustomAuthenticationProvider.java, (**here is where i decrypt and compare the user password)

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authLoginForm) throws AuthenticationException {

        String principal = authLoginForm.getName();
        String credenctials = (String) authLoginForm.getCredentials();

        User user = (User) customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal);

        if (user != null) {
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(credenctials, user.getPassword())) {
                System.out.println("Usuario identificado correctamente");
                                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal.toLowerCase(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Contraseña incorrecta");
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Error de autentificación");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Error de autentificación");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        User user = userService.findByAlias(authentication.getName().toLowerCase());

        **// CODE FOR REGISTER LOGIN USER**

        setDefaultTargetUrl("URL");
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.java

```
@Component
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (authentication != null) {
            // do something 
        }

        setDefaultTargetUrl("/login");
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);       
    }
}
```

CustomRememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler,java (**this code used when tried a solution where use a hablder for success form-login and other for success remember-me** --> [remember-me and authentication-success-handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575860/remember-me-and-authentication-success-handler/11678830#11678830))

```
@Service
public class CustomRememberMeAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        User user = userService.findByAlias(authentication.getName().toLowerCase());
        **// CODE FOR REGISTER LOGIN USER BY REMEMBER-ME**
    }
}
```

Comment: First at all, looking for info about the SecurityFilterChain, implements and override if needed only the RememberMeFilter, the handlers, are not really fired after one Filter has logged in the user setting him Principal into the SecurityContext (in this case the RememberMe), it's called after the SecurityFilterChain has logged the user successfuly. So, when the SuccessHandler is invoked, the Principal for the User is already stored in the SecurityContext.

Comment: i read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/remember-me.html and i do it, but doesn't capture remember me...

Sorry, I dont understand why. i need to look a correct real example working.. can you help me?

Comment: This example is pretty good -> http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-remember-me

Comment: my case is very more complex.. i need capture login with remember-me and login form for fire a specific code...the basic remember me method work fine.. but i need the cindicated functionality