# how to solve Spring Security can access url without login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i have created a sample spring mvc security application.I'm following java code based configuration rather than xml configuration.The application working fine.
But , a user can access each and every url without login the application. How can i resolve this problems??

i want , users must not be access url without login process.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)).and()
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and();
    }

    /*
     * @Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
     * throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use `Spring` `Filter`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928637/how-to-write-a-custom-filter-in-spring-security

Comment: thnx for the support.but my project based on spring boot,which means no web.xml file present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly include

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN"); // admin in your case
}
```

and as @Bohuslav Burghardt suggested use

```
 http
     .authorizeRequests()                                                                
     .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login").permitAll()   
     .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
     .and()

     .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
        .failureUrl("/loginfailed")             
        .permitAll()
        .and()

    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .invalidateHttpSession( true )
        .and();
```

Comment: I did some custom changes for you check.. If still not works, then there is some other problem.

Comment: it's worked..thnx.
also i want to handle logout problem. le:- after logout i can go back to homepage. and also same in home page i can goto login page when back button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the problem:

```
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

The order of the rules matters (it should be most specific first, least specific last), so the `/**` pattern will match everything and the `anyRequest().authenticated()` will never take effect (and therefore access to all URLs will be permitted for all). So the solution is to remove the `/**` rule or to make it less general, depending on what you want it to do.

Btw, you should really follow the [recommended conventions for indenting Spring Security Java configuration](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/spring-security-java-config-preview-readability/), it would make your configuration much more easier to read.