# Howto additionally add Spring Security captcha filter for specific urls only

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, captcha

I am looking for a non invasive way to add a captcha filter for certain api calls.

My setup consists of two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` with one filter each (not the captcha filter):

- **Internal api** ("/iapi" use Filter A on all calls but also ignore some **public** requests like /authenticate)
- **External api** ("/eapi" use Filter B on all calls)

How can I add a filter **before** the Spring Security stuff, on public, internal api or external api calls? I don't need the SecurityContext, just need to check for a Captcha in the request headers, forward to filterChain (normal filters) or manually deny access. I tried declaring a filter in web.xml, but that breaks the ability to use dependency injection.

Here is my Spring Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    public static class InternalApiConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Filter filterA;

        public InternalApiConfigurerAdapter() {
            super(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/public/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/iapi/**")
                    .exceptionHandling().and()
                    .anonymous().and()
                    .servletApi().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .addFilterBefore(filterA, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return authenticationManager();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    public static class ExternalApiConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private FilterB filterB;

        public ExternalApiConfigurerAdapter() {
            super(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/external/**")
                    .exceptionHandling().and()
                    .anonymous().and()
                    .servletApi().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .addFilterBefore(filterB, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return authenticationManager();
        }
    }
```

**Update:** At the moment I have a working configuration with a filter declared in web.xml. However, it has the drawback of being seperated from the Spring Context (e.g. no autowiring of beans), so I am looking for a better solution leveraging Spring.

**Summary**: There are two remaining problems:

1. add a filter for *specific urls* only - using beforeFilter(...) inside any configuration adds a filter to all urls of that configuration. Antmatchers didn't work. I need something like that: /iapi/captcha/*, /external/captcha/*, /public/captcha/*.
2. I have a public api which bypasses Spring Security completely: (web
                           .ignoring()
                           .antMatchers("/public/**");). I need to bypass Spring Security but still declare a filter there, using Spring autowiring but not necessarily Spring Security features, since my captcha filter only rejects or forwards calls in a stateless way.

Comment: You are speaking about `Filter A` and `Filter B`. Are they placeholders for your captcha filter or do you have a real implementation for it? If so, could you update your question accordingly?

Comment: not really sure if it is exactly what you are looking for, but found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11929129/4207875) to a similar question. The differences are that they add the filter at the end of the chain, and the config is in XML, but in javaconfig, the http.addFilterBefore() does the trick too.

Comment: @ksokol They are the filters of the current system, I don't want to touch them.

Comment: @SalvadorJuanMartinez I don't think it will work. It's a xml config, and my main problem is, that I want to add a filter before specific paths only in different configurations - so I wouldn't need to change my whole setup.

Comment: sorry, i guess i didn't explain myself clearly, i didn't mean change to XML config, and/or add the filter at the end, but instead, could be used as a reference, since it is a working example of how to add a custom filter to the chain. It provides information on how to implement the filters correctly. In your case you can stick to `.addFilterBefore() ` to insert the filter in the position you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You already have a working configuration with filters A and B inserted before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` so should be easy to add another custom filter.

First, you create the filter, and declare it as a bean, either annotating the class with `@Component`, or as a `@Bean` inside a `@Configuration` class, so it is ready to be injected with `@Autowired`.

Now you are able to inject it, as filter A and B, and use it. According to the [Filter Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering) section in the Spring Security reference documentation, the very first Filter in the chain is `ChannelProcessingFilter`, so in order to insert the filter before anything else in the Spring Security filter chain, you'd do this:

```
@Autowired
private CaptchaFilter captchaFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/iapi/**")
            .addFilterBefore(captchaFilter, (Class<? extends Filter>) ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(filterA, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

By the way, `exceptionHandling()` `anonymous()` and `servletApi()` aren't needed because when extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, these are already included, except for `anonymous()` when you actually specify more configuration details, as it states [`HttpSecurity` javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html)

Keep in mind that the Spring Security "entrypoint", the `DelegatingFilterProxy` still will be executed before your filter, but this component only delegates the request to the first filter in the chain, which in this case would be the CaptchaFilter, so you really would execute your filter before anything else from Spring Security.

But if you still want the captcha filter be executed before the `DelegatingFilterProxy`, there is no way to do so in the Spring Security configuration, and you need to declare it in the `web.xml` file.

---

Update: If you do not desire to include the captcha filter in the other configurations, you can always add a third configuration, and the configurations class would be as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class CaptchaApiConfigurerAdatper extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CaptchaFilter captchaFilter;

        public CaptchaApiConfigurerAdatper() {
            super(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/public/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers()
                        .antMatcher("/iapi/captcha**")
                        .antMatcher("/external/captcha**")
                        .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(captchaFilter, (Class<? extends Filter>) ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }            

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class InternalApiConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        // ommiting code for the sake of clarity
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class ExternalApiConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

         // ommiting code for the sake of clarity
    }
```

By the way, another tip, you can refactor all the common configuration outside the specific configurations, into the main class, like `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` the AuthenticationManager, the `WebSecurity` to skip security for the public, but for those since the main class is not extending anything you should `@Autowire` the method declarations.

Although there would be one problem with the `WebSecurity`, if you are ignoring `/public/**` the matcher for the `HttpSecurity` with `/public/captcha**` would be ignored, so i guess, you shouldnt refactor out the `WebSecurity` and have a different pattern in the CaptchaConfig class so it doesnt overlap.

Comment: Sorry, I have already tried that approach. It would use those two filters on any request, but I need specific paths. Also I still don't know how to add them on non Spring Security calls. I updated my question accordingly. Thanks for the hint about exception handling, that stuff helps me to understand Spring Security better!

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from adding a third configuration for the captcha filter, just keep in mind the `@Order`, i'll update the answer with an example.