# How do I use Spring Secuity to secure all CRUD operations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am leveraging Spring to create a web application where a `PortalUser` can access and create a `Ticket` accessible only by their `Company`.

By default, any authenticated user with read/write access can perform all CRUD operations. The problem is, an authenticated user can perform an operation outside of their `Company` by choosing an id they should not have access to.

Company *Foo* could very easily delete, view, etc a ticket from *Bar*, buy directly accessing the Ticket at ***example.com/tickets/{any id}***

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tickets")    
public class TicketController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "text/html")
    public String TicketController.show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel) {
           ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "text/html")
    public String TicketController.delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, Model uiModel){
    ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String TicketController.listDatatables(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Without modifying each method in every controller, is there a way to ensure that users cannot access data that is outside of the intended scope?

It seems that a [custom Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928637/how-to-write-a-custom-filter-in-spring-security), could be of use, and I am able to filter out Companies on GET's by cloning and modifying the parameter map, but I haven't found a way solution would work for all methods.

Comment: Which version of Roo are you using?

Comment: @eruiz I'm using 2.0.0.M1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a way to prevent users from creating or modifying tickets is to add a validator to `Ticket`.

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(sequenceName = "TICKET_SEQ", finders = { "findTicketsByCompany", "findTicketsByPerson" })
public class Ticket {
    @ValidCompany
    Company;
    //....
}
```

We can add the logic to grab the current user's credentials, and check that they are in the same `Company` of the `Ticket` they are creating / modifying.

```
public class CompanyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCompany, Company> {

@Override
public void initialize(ValidCompany validCompany) {
}

public CompanyValidator() {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Company company, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    //logic 
    Company portalUserCompany = null;
    try {
        PortalUser portalUser = (PortalUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        portalUserCompany = portalUser.getCompany(); 
        //In this case we are getting the PortalUser's Company, but you could get a user's authorities instead.
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return portalUserCompany != null && portalUserCompany.getId().equals(company.getId());

}
```

And the Interface:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CompanyValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidCompany {
    String message() default "{validator.company}";//Error message to be displayed if the CompanyValidator isValid returns false
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
}
```