# How to create your own security filter using Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to know whether it is possible to create your own security filter in Spring Web application using Spring Security API ? I want to create a generic filter for security so that it can be used (plugged) for any web application simply by adding that Filter in web.xml. The security module should be independent of all web application. The web application can be full fledged web application or it can be a restful web service. The whole objective is to add that library from Nexus and add to any web application by adding a simple filter without any hassle.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a custom filter in spring security?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928637/how-to-write-a-custom-filter-in-spring-security)

Comment: Hi Matan, I have already gone through this post before posting my question. It is not what I want, basically I want to create my own custom filter so that instead of Spring security , I want to use a generic Filter only no other Spring security filter or DelegatingFilterProxy. It should be single module to be plugged to any web application.