# How to create a custom Authorization Filter in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, abac

I have a use case where I need to secure the endpoints of my application through ABAC Authorization. The code to perform ABAC Authorization is already present.
I found several examples on How to create custom Authentication filter in Spring Security.
One of them is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708171/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-filter-in-spring-security).
Is there a similar standardized way to implement a custom AuthorizationFilter in Spring Security ?

Is there an object similar to Authentication that needs to be set in Spring's Security context?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Security 5.5, `AuthorizationFilter` and [`AuthorizationManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8900) were introduced.

You can construct an `AuthorizationManager`, provide it [in the DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L1423):

```java
http
    // ...
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .anyRequest().access(myAuthorizationManager())
    )
    // ..
```

and the DSL will construct an `AuthorizationFilter` with your custom manager.

If you are on an earlier version of Spring Security, you can instead [wire an `AccessDecisionManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization).